# Ошибка при запуске Unittest: AttributeError: module 'math' has no attribute 'add'

Tags: python

math.py

```
def add(x, y=4):
    return x + y
```

test_math.py

```
import unittest
import math


class TestMath(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_add(self):
        result = math.add(5, 7)
        self.assertEqual(result, 12)
```

Comment: Не называйте свои файлы так же, как называются стандартные модули питона. Название math уже занято

Comment: всё ровно, ошибка таже

Comment: а нет всё роботоает, спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Модуль `math` - это стандартный модуль `Python`, который будет импортироваться вместо вашего `math.py`. Переименуйте `math.py` в, например, `math_.py`. И, да, не очень правильно задавать значение переменной прямо в `def`:

```py
def add(x, y=4):
    return x + y
```

Лучше делайте так:

```py
def add(x, y):
    return x + y


# вызов функции
print(add(x, 4)) # вместо 'x' подставьте Ваше число
```

Comment: Ну, дефолтное значение параметра - это вообще-то нормально в каких-то случаях.